# Open neighborhood of some manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $K \subset M $ be a submanifold of a differentiable manifold $M$. 

**Problem:** Show that for all $p \in K$ there exist an open neighborhood $K^{'}$ in $M$ such that $K \cap K^{'}$ is closed in $K^{'}$. 

**Definition:** Let $M$ be a manifold in $\mathbb R^{\ell}$. A submanifold of $M$ is a subset $K \subset M$, which is also a manifold in $\mathbb R^{\ell}$.

What I have done so far:
 Using this **Corollary:** If $N \subset M$ is a submanifold of an abstract manifold, then
there exists for each $p \in N$ an open neighborhood $W \in M$ and a smooth
map $\phi : W \longrightarrow N$ such that $\phi(x) = x$ for all $x \in W \cap N$. 
  Now it almost solved the problem, the only problem left is the closeness of $K \cap K^{'}$ in $K^{'}$. Is it automatically closed?

I've played around with it and still I don't know what to do here. 
 Any hints and help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Let me edit the question ill add the definition.

Comment: The thing you're trying to prove is false. For example, let $M=\mathbb R$ and let $K$ be the interval $(-1,1)$. Then there is no open neighborhood $K'$ of $0$ such that $(-1,1)\cap K'$ is closed in $\mathbb R$. Are you sure the problem didn't ask for $K\cap K'$ to be closed in $K'$?

Comment: My bad i didn't even find a counterexaple to that, that is indeed false. Maybe a typo error in the book. Thank you very much for correcting it should be $K^{'}$.